# Output reflection coefficient of a two port network

Tags: rf, microwave

[image]In the third edition of the textbook Microwave Engineering by David Pozar, example 4.7, it is explained how to use signal flow graphs to find the output reflection coefficient \$\Gamma_{out}\$ of a two port network. The expression for \$\Gamma_{out}\$ turns out to be independent of the value of the load impedance, however, I am confused as to how this can be reconciled with the fact that  \$\Gamma_{out} = b_2/a_2\$ and \$\Gamma_{load} = a_2/b_2 = 1/\Gamma_{out}\$ , making the value of \$\Gamma_{out}\$ completely determined by that of \$\Gamma_{load}\$ and consequently by the load impedance \$Z_L\$.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Including the example you cited, or drawings from the example, would probably help make your question more clear. Partiicularly, enough information to define \$a_2\$, \$b_2\$, etc.

Comment: Has your text previously defined the S-parameters?

Comment: Yes , S-Parameters are defined

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the difference is that \$\Gamma_{out}\$ is defined when a stimulus is applied from the load side (and the "input" side is properly terminated), while \$\Gamma_{load}\$ is defined when stimulus is provided from the input side of the DUT.

But it's hard to be sure of this without seeing the definitions made in your text.

Comment: Isn't this a definition of S-parameters?

Comment: From the formula you gave, it looks like your book is defining \$\Gamma_{out}\$ as the reflection when a matched source is applied on the output side, but accounting for a possibly mismatched source connected on the input side. If the input-side source were perfectly matched, then you'd get \$\Gamma_{out}=S_{22}\$.

Comment: So the difference between \$\Gamma_{out}\$ and \$\Gamma_{load}\$ is that one is a response to a stimulus coming from the right and the other is a response to a stimulus coming from the left. But he didn't assume perfect termination on the left like I guessed he would.